# How can I solve Error during testing Angular Js in netbeans?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, netbeans-7.3

After following this example

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/html5-js-support.html

I always get that error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/jstestdriver/hooks/TestListener
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2694)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1622)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.jstestdriver.hooks.TestListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 6 more
```

I want to know why is that happening and how to solve that problem

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the *JsTestDriver jar* to your lib folder, as listed in the *resources table*.

The file is available here: https://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/downloads/list

Comment: Thanks David, the problem was that I added the wrong File. I added the "src" file instead the correct one.

Comment: Good to hear. Consider marking the question answered, if the answer helped.

Comment: @DavidRiccitelli Pardon the ignorance, but which lib folder are you referring to? I don't see a lib folder in my Java install and the lib in the angular root doesn't seem appropriate as it only contains js files. Thanks if you can answer this.

Comment: @DavidRiccitelli I read through the example link OP posted, my situation is different, I'm trying to build angular from my local clone.